# ajax request withing phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, cross-domain

I was trying to make AJAX request to some website in the localhost within phonegap but it's not working and I got just failure and i tried a lot of ways to it but nothing happened

and when I try doing it with some local file for the phonegap it works 100%

I have read that its cross domain problem so I tried jSONP and nothing it could be a problem from the emulator or phonegap or maybe there is a specific way to do it

Please Help

this is one of the solutions I tried

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://127.0.0.1/test/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg){
           alert(msg);
        }
     }
  )
```

I tried emulating it using DW 5.5 and its worked normally how can i fix this on eclipse

Comment: Is there a server running on the phone? That is capable to deliver php?

Comment: No the server running on the PC

Comment: Perhaps you should enter the IP of the PC - 127.0.0.1 is the localhost of the phone. But you want to talk to your PC!

Comment: I Was testing it , but it also doesn't work BTW I tried XMLHttpRequest and the status was 0

Comment: I assume the phone and the PC are on the same wlan without any firewall blocking them? Can you call the page in the normal webbrowser (on phone and PC)?

Comment: Your assumption is right and yes its working normally

Comment: I tried emulating it using DW 5.5 and its worked normally how can i fix this bug on eclipse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change url: "http://127.0.0.1 to the IP address of the PC where the php server is running.  On MacOS and Linux, the ifconfig command will tell you the IP address. Get that IP address and replace the //127.0.0.1 in your source.

Comment: I already did that before :) BTW it wasn't a problem 
I tried emulating it using DW 5.5 and its worked normally how can i fix this on eclipse

Comment: What did you change the IP address to? 127.0.0.1 works on the emulator because it's running on the same host as your PC. When you run on the device, you need a real IP address, not a localhost.

Answer (score 0):

yes palcoder.... I have this issue too... it has taken a whole day to find the problem.

Its the eclipse who is the culprit... After so many times checking with hit and trial I came to know

that running on localmachine will not allow the ajax jsonp process to execute. You should use a

different domain... and it works like a charm...

Hope some one doesn't waste time on localhost just like me.  :)